# Matching in regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find many scripts from vscode

I have this code, but it needs improvement.

for

I need to match all cases

Comment: You have whitespace after the first two `1`'s -that is why they aren't matching.  You have the end of line `$` right after the `1`'s so those will not match.  The last five lines do match.

Comment: you have spaces and TABs, a space character only matches a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace spaces `" *"` with `\s*`:

```
^@ApplicationTenantLinkId\s*BIGINT\s*=\s*1\s*$
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/oD7ebb/1)

Comment: Many Thanks, Working as expected,